# Check input if start with then submit to the right action Php html

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, validation

Please I need help 
I have a form with an input text

```
<?php 
if($input == ‘aab’ or ‘aac’){
    $action = " http://mywebsite.com /women/search=$input"; 
}else if($input == ‘aad’ or ‘aaf’ or ‘aat’){
    $action =" http://mywebsite.com /men/search=$input”;
}
?>
<form action= "<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post">
<input id="Input" name="Input" class="input-block-level "></p>


                    <p class="pull-right" ><button id="Search" class="btn" >                    Search

                </form>
```

It have two different actions for example if the input text start with aab or aac then it will submit to http://mywebsite.com /women/search=$input
 And if the input text value start with aad or aaf or aat action wil be
to http://mywebsite.com /men/search=$input
So first we will check if the input start by aab or aac or aad or aat… then subit to the right url

Comment: `‘’`  - smart quotes, beautiful yet deadly.

Comment: You have double `$$`.. Please tell me the above is psuedocode

Comment: your `else if` makes no sense and is invalid. Your entire post doesn't hold water.

Comment: ‘’ and $$, == == in else if is invalid, it makes no sense

Comment: I for one, will not be rewriting your code; I'm out.

Comment: Guess I am that one to re-write the code. Hopefully the OP takes something from it. 2 minutes of my life wasted if he doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not possible with the PhP. you can do it with the help of Javascript, i will suggest you to use jQuery. Something like below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#Input').change(function(){
        var input = $('#Input').val(),
            status = input.substring(0,3);
        if(status === "aad" || status === "aaf" || status === "aat"){
            $('form').attr('action', 'http://mywebsite.com/men/search='+input);
        }else if(status === "aab" || status === "aac"){
            $('form').attr('action', 'http://mywebsite.com/women/search='+input);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Don't forgot to include Jquery.

Comment: `if`/`else if` would be cleaner using `$.inArray(input, ['aab', 'aab', 'aac'])`

Comment: @MrMarlow yes you are right but it is li'l bit typical as he is at beginning stage. and note here we will use `$.inArray(status, ['aab', 'aab', 'aac'])` , we have to also take care of index 0

Comment: @santosh  thank u  very much  would like please to edit the code to make stauts as array  because the possiblities are more than 22

Comment: @faucot,  I have mentioned that in my comment on this answer. Compare this function return value to -1

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace $variable, for what you are actually checking against, but this should work for what you want.

Added some notes in comments, to explain a little.

```
<?php
// Default action for if none is matched below in if/elseif clause
// by default, this will search the location you are not.
$action = '';

// Replace $variable with the variable you are checking against.
// The variable has to exist AND contain at least 3 characters
$input  = isset($variable) && strlen($variable) > 3 ? substr($variable, 0, 3) : false;

// Check the $input variable is not false, and is either 'aab' or 'aac'
if ($input && in_array($input, array('aab', 'aac'))) {
    $action = 'http://mywebsite.com/women/search=' . $input;

// Otherwise check if $input is set and is either: aad, aaf or aat
} else if ($input && in_array($input, array('aad', 'aaf', 'aat'))) {
    $action = 'http://mywebsite.com/men/search=' . $input;
}

if (strlen($action)) {
    echo <<<JS
        <script>
        document.location.href='$action';
        </script>
JS;
    exit;
}

// Output form. You were missing closing elements etc.
echo <<<FORM
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input id="Input" name="Input" class="input-block-level">
            <p class="pull-right">
                <button id="Search" class="btn" >Search</button>
            </p>
    </form>
FORM;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and for this solution, what i am checking is if the Input text value STARTSWITH for exemple it can aab5264 or aab4715

Comment: Yes, I understood that, but where does the code come from? Is it in the URL, or generated elsewhere?

Comment: $variable should be the value of tje input text

Comment: I have added the extra block in the middle, which makes a call to javascript for the redirect. PHP can redirect, but only if headers are not sent - which I can't confirm, so reverted to native javascript. Ignore the `need jQuery` nonsense above - `jQuery IS NOT NEEDED`